# Jquery loads on first page load, but not when reloaded in ajax div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The first time my page loads, all content loads correctly.
When loading a the same section of the page again using Ajax (to refresh content), the Jquery does not fully load.

Is this because the first time Jquery is activated by 'on page load' or something, so when opened in ajax window - the page hasn't actually reloaded, so Jquery isnt activated?

Here's the code I think causes the issue .. does it just need to activating when opened in an ajax div?

```
<!-- Once the page is loaded, initalize the plug-in. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($){
      var handler = $('#tiles li');

      handler.wookmark({
          // Prepare layout options.
          autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
          container: $('#main'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
          offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
          outerOffset: 0, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
          itemWidth: 178 // Optional, the width of a grid item
      });

        // Update the layout.
        handler.wookmark();
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
```

I should mention that the Jquery is being used for styling reasons (it cleverly styles the page content). I would guess that happens when `handler.wookmark();` is activated. How can I activate this in the ajax window?

I've been asked to provide my ajax code, so here it is:

```
<!-- ajax script -->
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        var otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            favorites.className = 'filterOption';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var otherClasses = everyone.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            favorites.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            everyone.className = 'filterOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
</script>
<!-- ends ajax script -->
```

Comment: I think you need to use delegate; so you can write something like this:

     $( "table" ).delegate( "td", "click", function() {
       $( this ).toggleClass( "chosen" );
     });

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the above comment.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to load with your Ajax code? And why do you think that jQuery isn't fully loaded? Are there any console errors? What part of your page isn't loaded, is it the Ajax part?

Comment: What does your ajax part look like? Can you put this code in the callback to reinitialize it?

Comment: The Jquery turns database results into <li> items and then styles and positions them on the page, depending on the size of the content being drawn from the database. When loading the same content again in the ajax window, content isn't displayed on screen, but IS there when viewing the page source. CSS is setting it to be hidden and not positioned.

Comment: Then simply run your styling jquery code in the ajax success() method.

Comment: My knowledge of this language is very limited. I wouldn't know how to do that :(

Answer (score 2):

I am a freaking genius, I solved my own problem! (This has never happened before :D)

I had to add the javascript into my ajax coding so it would be re-read once the ajax refreshed.

ANSWER:

```
<!-- ajax script -->
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        favorites = document.getElementById('favorites');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        var otherClasses = favorites.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            favorites.className = 'filterOption';
        }
    }

    favorites.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexFav');        
        var otherClasses = everyone.className;
        if (otherClasses.contains("Active")) {
            favorites.className = 'filterOptionActive';
            everyone.className = 'filterOption';
        }
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;






// this is the content that needed adding!
(function ($){
          var handler = $('#tiles li');

          handler.wookmark({
              // Prepare layout options.
              autoResize: true, // This will auto-update the layout when the browser window is resized.
              container: $('#main'), // Optional, used for some extra CSS styling
              offset: 5, // Optional, the distance between grid items
              outerOffset: 0, // Optional, the distance to the containers border
              itemWidth: 178 // Optional, the width of a grid item
          });

          // Capture clicks on grid items.
          handler.click(function(){
            // Randomize the height of the clicked item.
            var newHeight = $('img', this).height() + Math.round(Math.random() * 300 + 30);
            $(this).css('height', newHeight+'px');

            // Update the layout.
            handler.wookmark();
          });
        })(jQuery);






                }
              }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../home/" + pageName + ".php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            }
    }
    </script>
    <!-- ends ajax script -->
```

Comment: i just tried to say you needed to run your code inside ajax, what is you currently did..

Answer (score 0):

If i understood it right, you need to perform your code also in the:

```
...
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            //Here
            handler.wookmark()
            }
...
```

If there is error with **handler** in the upper code, then make variable global: in your code

```
(function ($){
      var handler = $('#tiles li');
      window.handler = handler
```

and edit first code in my answer:

```
                //Here
                window.handler.wookmark()
```

Comment: I couldn't say if this is the right or wrong answer because my knowledge of this language is limited. I couldn't begin to make the above code relevant to my script. :(

Comment: I've added it into my question

Comment: Edited answer according to ajax call.

Comment: No such luck. This is driving me crazy!